# AppStoreConnect - Cant Submit App For Review ?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

So I've been working on my own app , I finally finished everything and my app is ready to publish , I completed each step to publish my app to the AppStore . So I visited [AppStoreConnect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) to publish my app , But I cant submit the App because the "Submit App Review" button isnt clickable .

Any idea why this is occurring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is the holiday schedule. As per Apple:

> **App Store Connect Holiday Schedule: Dec 23–27**
>
> Make sure your apps are
>   up to date and ready for the holidays. New apps and app updates will
>   not be accepted December 23 to 27 (Pacific Time), so any releases
>   should be submitted, approved, and scheduled in advance. Other App
>   Store Connect and developer account features will remain available.

If you feel this isn't the cause for your issue, then the next thing to check is that you haven't forgotten to provide some info in one of the required fields. Any fields with missing data will be highlighted for your convenience.

One thing that also catches people out is the **Build**. Make sure you've clicked on the + symbol to choose the build you want to submit.

Comment: Well, I already included the build , but it seems to me that the issue because the Holiday Schedule you just mentioned , Thanks. .